# Disable admin or frontend route

Tags: admin, magento-1, routing

Is there a way to disable an admin route, well actually any route. The use case is I have an extension that comes with a frontend section and an admin section but I do not want the admin section to be used. I have disabled the admin menu items but I would like to disable the route as well so that if there are any other links or someone has it bookmarked they get a 404 or redirected to the dashboard.

I know I could setup different roles and disable for some roles but I want it to be a complete removal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this without removing the `routers` tag from the `config.xml` or adding some observers on the predispatch event that will redirect you to a 404 page.
But I may be wrong. In case I'm wrong here is a place to start.
The `routers` section of the `config.xml` files is parsed in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::collectRoutes`.
From what I saw in there, there is no check for a `disabled` flag or something like that.
There might be a chance if the the module does not use the `admin` path for backend pages.
So if the router is not declared like this:

```
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Module_Name before="Mage_Adminhtml">Module_Name_Adminhtml</Module_Name>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
```

but uses the other way of declaring routers:

```
    <routers>
        <module_name>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Module_Name</module>
                <frontName>route_name</frontName>
            </args>
        </module_name>
    </routers>
```

You can create a module and just change the `<use>` tag value to something that's not `admin` or `standard`.

So your new module that depends on the original one can have the routers section like this:

```
<routers>
    <module_name>
        <use>go-away</use>
    </module_name>
</routers>
```

Why I thing it could work? because in the method mentioned above the only `if` with no `else` that could return false is `if ($use == $useRouterName)`.
This is just an assumption. I haven't tested it. I don't have any extensions that use this type of routers for backend.

Comment: Not a bad idea, with the `use` then you end up on a front-end 404 page, but that is not so bad in this case.

Comment: @DavidManners. Just curious, how did you did it?

Comment: I did it with `<use>we-do-not-want-this-module</use>` it gives you a front end 404 page but that is completely fine for me. Open to other ideas though.

Comment: Nice! That's how I disabled the product review functionality and it works well

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just do something like rewrite the relevant controller action and then just have a redirect to dashboard or some other page.

Comment: yeah I was thinking about this but some modules can have a lot of actions, I was also thinking about simply changing the frontName to so random string

Comment: Sure ok, how about a `<from>` `<to>` config.xml rewrite then.  As it's under `<global>` it should work for admin as well?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use `preDispatch` to do this job for you. Try this code inside your modules's admin controller

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    parent::preDispatch();
    //Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
       // Mage::helper('cms')->__('Requested URL is not allowed'));
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/dashboard/index"));

}
```

I have tried this in `CMS > Pages` controller and it works just fine. I tried to add an error message, but it didn't work. I think you will be able to resolve it. If you find, why the error message didn't work, inform me too :-)

Comment: My idea was to not use code but to simply turn the router off like you can with other items like the menu or observers. With your answer I would have to write a bit of config and a controller, though it would be small, as I do not want to directly edit the modules code. Not saying it is wrong just noting my thinking.

Comment: so you dont have controller for your extension? I was not aware of it. anyway I am leaving this answer here. It may help future visitors :)

Comment: it was more about disabling another extensions controller. sure I can write mine that extends it no problem. Just wanted some ideas about different ways