# How to disable the customer frontend in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, rest-api

My app only uses the Magento 2 `REST API` and the admin backend. How can I disable the frontend the customer interacts with?

PS:
Seen this post, but it is an older one: [Disable admin or frontend route](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37089/disable-admin-or-frontend-route)

Comment: bob, code is  updated,please check

Answer (score 2):

### Module is tested

Bob, you can do this by magento [**event/observer**](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html).

For this, you need define an observer which will  fire on event **`controller_action_predispatch`** .

Also note event should ***be define for frontend area***,so that i will only **working on frontend**

So you need to define **events.xml** it at *app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/frontend*

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="myObserverName" instance="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer\ObserverforDisabledFrontend" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer Code may be**,

```
 <?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class ObserverforDisabledFrontend implements ObserverInterface
{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
     */
    protected $redirect;


    /**
     * @var Magento\Backend\Helper\Data
     */
    private $HelperBackend;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $HelperBackend
    ) {
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->HelperBackend = $HelperBackend;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        /*$this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(),
         'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=OHoGWLzeIqnT8geDpr3wDQ');*/

         $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(),$this->HelperBackend->getHomePageUrl());

    }

}
```

**Note:** Assume that your admin url is *`http://www.example.com/admin`*.

Full module is available at [GitHub repo devamitbera/Magento2-extension](https://github.com/devamitbera/Magento2-extension/tree/master/Disabled-frontend)

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm going to dig into this, will get back to it asap.

Comment: Hi @Amit unfortunately this disables everything, the REST api and admin aren't available now.

Comment: bob, i have check in default magento 2.1, it is working

Comment: @BobvanLuijt Did you get the solution?