# Disable area in magento2

Tags: magento2, area

In magento we have following areas by default.

- admin
- adminhtml
- catalog
- crontab
- doc
- frontend
- global
- setup
- webapi_rest
- webapi_soap

How to disable particular area? for example `front end` area?

update:
completely remove frontend area.

I need only rest ,soap, adminhtml, admin, setup, cron.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following module:
https://github.com/abelbm/magento2-disable-frontend.

Comment: i will use magento only for rest api calls. i need to remove completely.

Comment: this module description saying this "
Disable the frontend in Magento 2 for using only the Admin and the API routes."

Comment: there is similar question already there on the stackexchange, you can refer this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141432/32047